# How to update language in service worker from a Spring client app

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In my service worker, I have to generate some text. The problem is updating service worker language when app language changes. The only idea I have is having a service worker for every language, which is not a scalable solution.

The client app that is registering the service worker is a Spring app, in which I get locale using `pageContext.response.locale.language` (not compatible with JS).

Are there any other approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I guess you need to communicate the change of the language setting to the Service Worker. You can communicate that from the application's regular JS code via the postMessage API. Using postMessage, you can send arbitrary messages from the page to the SW and vice-versa.

Then it's a matter of what your SW does after receiving the message. Maybe it then generates different text based on the chosen language. This way you only have one SW that knows how to generate different language versions of the text and it does so depending on the lang setting of the user.